How to add and configure the AI Assistant plugin in CKEditor?
I'm working on integrating CKEditor with React, specifically focusing on configuring plugins like AI Assistant and handling file uploads using UploadAdapter. However, I'm having trouble adding and configuring the AI Assistant plugin in CKEditor.
CKEditor Configuration: I'm using CKEditor 5 with a custom build that includes several plugins such as Bold, Italic, Link, and others.
React Integration: The editor is integrated with a React application.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
